# how to create radio button with images

Tags: html

I want to have a radio button with images instead of text. So I want to have an image of male and female instead of a text of male and female. Can this actually be done using a standard HTML or do I have to use jQuery? How do I do this?

Comment: I misread your question. I thought you wanted to replace the *radio buttons* with images.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `<label>` elements to host your images, like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" id="male-radio">
<label for="male-radio"><img src="male.gif"></label>

<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" id="female-radio">
<label for="female-radio"><img src="female.gif"></label>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/RichieHindle/vQwCF/