# Toggling between two onclick functions

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created two buttons in HTML and I have written some jQuery so that when the user clicks one of the button, a new CSS rule will be applied to that button. This code works below:

```
$('#approve').on('click', function(){
    $('#approve:hover').css("background-color", "#24ce3a")
    $('#approve:hover').css("color","#FFF")
});
$('#reject').on('click', function(){
    $('#reject:hover').css("background-color", "#e32e10")
    $('#reject:hover').css("color", "#FFF")
});
```

If `#approve` is clicked, I want to give it a new color and disable the `#reject` button. The next time `#approve` is clicked, I want to reset to the original styling, and re-enable the `#reject` button. The `#reject` button should have similar behavior: toggle it's own state when clicked, and disable the `#approve` button while it's active.

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Comment: So? what's the difference? Can't you simply use it the way it's meant to be used? `$(this)` without the `:hover` (unexistant selector AFAIK)

Comment: @GhostDZ9 What exactly do you mean by "I don't want #reject to toggle"? What do you want to happen when a button is clicked? If I click `#approve` what happens to that button? And what happens to the other one? What happens if I click it again? This isn't really clear from your question...

Comment: @nbrooks +1 I was writing the same. It's not clear at all should the buttons toggle on them selves, or simply do a one-time click-pick bye-bye.

Comment: @nbrooks Its basically like a switch if one is click the other button shouldn't be clickable.

Comment: @GhostDZ9 ok, but what after? what should happen if one clicks again the same button? Sould it go back-to-normal?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes it should go back to its normal state without the css being applied

Comment: Food for thought: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/39080/buttons-instead-of-radio-buttons-or-a-dropdown?newreg=30a9aab6cc0f4f3688d17ed98cee81ae (see the top two answers in particular)

Comment: @TroyGizzi not exactly the same.

Comment: @GhostDZ9 I'd really go with classic radio buttons or at least with the exact behavior they apply.

Comment: @GhostDZ9 Please realize that if you take away the user's ability to click the other button after they've already clicked one, they are going to be frustrated and unhappy when they try to change their selection. I strongly encourage you to rethink your design. The approach that Roko just suggested (_go with classic radio buttons or at least with the exact behavior they apply_) is much better than what you're attempting to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When one of the callback functions is triggered, have it disable the other one by adding a class to it. The next time it's clicked, re-enable the button by removing the class.

```js
var approveFunc = function() {
  if ($(this).is(".disabled")) {
    return;
  }
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $("#reject").toggleClass("disabled");
};

var rejectFunc = function() {
  if ($(this).is(".disabled")) {
    return;
  }
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $("#approve").toggleClass("disabled");
};

$('#approve').on('click', approveFunc);
$('#reject').on('click', rejectFunc);
```

```css
div {
  color: blue;
  background-color: pink;
}
#approve.active {
  background-color: #24ce3a;
  color: #FFF;
}
#reject.active {
  background-color: #e32e10;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="approve">Approve</div>
<div id="reject">Reject</div>
```

Comment: This nearly works, Approve works as expected but reject doesn't.

Comment: @GhostDZ9 Oh sorry, had a typo in the reject code! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Just as different approach - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hhbqpue/)

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function () {
  if ($(".selected").length === 0 | $(this).hasClass("selected"))
  {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  }
});
```

Instead of changing the inline css I've added the class `selected`.

As mentioned in the comments, the check for elements with the class `selected` should be narrowed down according to the actual markup to avoid unwanted results. E.g. in case both buttons are in a div with an `id="testing"` it could be `$("#testing .selected").length` to only check for the elements in question.

Comment: UX concern: If a user clicks one button, and then they change their mind and try to click the other, but find out they can't, they're going to get frustrated. It's not intuitive that you need to re-click the first button before you can then click the other button.

Comment: @TroyGizzi on that matter you're completely right! They should behave like radio buttons, if there's a concern about design than: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541614/use-thumbnail-image-instead-of-radio-button/17541916#17541916

Comment: @TroyGizzi Thanks for mentioning, share the concern, but that's how I understood the requirement of OP.

Comment: P.S: be careful, there could be other `.selected` on a single page. It's a commonly used className

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks for mentioning, in small fiddle examples I tend not to take care about further unknown markup.

Comment: @matthias_h all fine, it was just a note for the OP