# How to keep :active css style after click a button

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Once the button is clicked I want it to stay with the active style instead of going back to normal style.  Can this be done with CSS please? Im using blurb button from DIVI Theme (WordPress). Please help me!

code:

```css
    #blurb-hover.et_pb_blurb .et_pb_blurb_content 
    .et_pb_main_blurb_image .et-pb-icon:hover {
           color: red !important; }
    
    #blurb-hover.et_pb_blurb .et_pb_blurb_content 
    .et_pb_main_blurb_image .et-pb-icon:selected {
      background-color: #ff4b46;
      color: #fff; }

    #blurb-hover.et_pb_blurb .et_pb_blurb_content 
    .et_pb_main_blurb_image .et-pb-icon:active {
        color: white !important;
       background-color: red; 
        width: 140px;
        height: 100px; }
```

Comment: This is way too little info. What does the button do? Does it redirect you to a new page? What does your HTML look like? What is your desired result?

Comment: Jquery [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

Comment: Im trying to put this functionally code in wordpress.. but when i click, the icon/image on my web, it does not keep selected. What is wrong?

code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/La8wQ/660/

Comment: It's cool that the code I wrote is still used! Original: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20430219/1019059

Answer (score 96):

### CSS

`:active` denotes the interaction state (so for a button will be applied during press), `:focus` may be a better choice here. However, the styling will be lost once another element gains focus.

The final potential alternative using CSS would be to use `:target`, assuming the items being clicked are setting routes (e.g. anchors) within the page- however this can be interrupted if you are using routing (e.g. Angular), however this doesnt seem the case here.

```css
.active:active {
  color: red;
}
.focus:focus {
  color: red;
}
:target {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class='active'>Active</button>
<button class='focus'>Focus</button>
<a href='#target1' id='target1' class='target'>Target 1</a>
<a href='#target2' id='target2' class='target'>Target 2</a>
<a href='#target3' id='target3' class='target'>Target 3</a>
```

### Javascript / jQuery

As such, there is no way in CSS to *absolutely* toggle a styled state- if none of the above work for you, you will either need to combine with a change in your HTML (e.g. based on a checkbox) or programatically apply/remove a class using e.g. jQuery

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('button').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
button.selected{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Item</button><button>Item</button><button>Item</button>
```

Comment: Can I use that CSS code on an image instead of an link/button ??

Comment: `:target` can only be used in conjunction with navigator route, so the URL of the page will need to be changed accordingly so wrap the image in `a`, `focus` requires a tabbable element, so set `tabindex='0'` on the image

Answer (score 11):

We're going to to be using a hidden checkbox.
This example includes one "on click - off click 'hover / active' state"

--

To make content itself clickable:

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="activate-div">
  <label for="activate-div">
   <div class="my-div">
      //MY DIV CONTENT
   </div>
  </label>
```

**CSS**

```
#activate-div{display:none}    

.my-div{background-color:#FFF} 

#activate-div:checked ~ label 
.my-div{background-color:#000}
```

To make button change content:

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="activate-div">
   <div class="my-div">
      //MY DIV CONTENT
   </div>

<label for="activate-div">
   //MY BUTTON STUFF
</label>
```

**CSS**

```
#activate-div{display:none}

.my-div{background-color:#FFF} 

#activate-div:checked + 
.my-div{background-color:#000}
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 1):

In the [Divi Theme Documentation](http://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/divi/documentation/theme-options/), it says that the theme comes with access to 'ePanel' which also has an 'Integration' section.

You should be able to add this code:

```
<script>
 $( ".et-pb-icon" ).click(function() {
 $( this ).toggleClass( "active" );
 });
</script>
```

into the the box that says 'Add code to the head of your blog' under the 'Integration' tab, which should get the jQuery working.

Then, you should be able to style your class to what ever you need.