# Cycle displayed element without :checked, :target CSS only

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to cycle between 5 or 6 currencies and only want to be able to display one currency at any given time. I can't use input tags (no :checked pseudoclass) and :target due to platform restrictions (I'm working within a rich text widget that can't navigate to a fragment identifier).

Supported HTML tags:

"br"
"div"
"span"
"i"
"b"
"strong"
"s"
"strike"
"u"
"em"
"blockquote"
"tt"
"sup"
"sub"
"small"
"mark"
"del"
"ins"
"ul"
"ol"
"li"
"dl"
"dt"
"dd"
"h1"
"h2"
"h3"
"h4"
"h5"
"h6"
"hr"
"a"

The fiddle I'm working on: http://jsfiddle.net/nAg7W/803/
I'm hoping to have the HKD currency remain on the screen after clicking on the HKD link and then clicking elsewhere.

I've tried to toggle using the display: none; / display: block; properties, but found out from trial & error + this thread ([Transitions on the display: property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property)) that it won't work. With :focus, as soon as I click another element on the page I revert back to USD.

```css
div p {
  transition: opacity 0s;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative
}
div p#usd {
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
}
div p#hkd {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#hkd-toggle:focus ~ #hkd {
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
}
#hkd-toggle:focus ~ #usd {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="usd-toggle">USD</a> 
      <a href="#" id="hkd-toggle">HKD</a> 
      <p id="usd">suhh</p>
      <p id="hkd">duuude</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this with purely CSS? I was hoping there could be a delay on persisting the focus state but it seems to be a dead end. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I was reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31178653/how-to-keep-active-css-style-after-click-a-button and I think I blocked out the part where SW4 says you can't *absolutely* toggle with purely CSS. Really hoping someone clever can prove him wrong.

Comment: When you say "toggle" do you mean click the link once and it's state changes, click the same link a second time and it reverts back to it's original state?

Comment: Can you speak to the limitations of the platform? In particular, what makes it impossible to toggle with `:target`? Do you have any ability to change the URL or a portion of the URL? Do you have a whitelist of tags you can use?

Comment: You may take a look at infinite transition delay hack. [Example](http://dabblet.com/gist/2076449)

Comment: @zer00ne essentially I'm trying to be able to switch between 5 or 6 currencies and only want to be able to display 1 currency at any given time.

Comment: @Simon Ok, see my answer when you are able to.

Answer (score 1):

In **Snippet 2**, we will use an incredibly extended time delay on the "off" state of the target elements. Basicly what this does is force a state as usual but instead of milliseconds or seconds, we will set the delay to about 10 million seconds which will be about 120 days. So in this 120 day delay, the target element will still be in the "on" state. I tried to create a new set of buttons to reset the targets, but I'm running out of time, maybe with this head start you could figure the reset function.

In **Snippet 1**, there's only one visible pseudo-selector to use given that `:target` and `:clicked`, etc are not an option. For extra content, you can use `:before` and `.after`.

#### SNIPPET 2

```css
body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font: 600 20px/1.5 Times;
}
a,
a:link,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}
a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
/* 
| -Make your hidden state for target 
| -Add a very long delay time on the
| transition property. As long as the
| transition is moving towards it's goal
| to complete the animation in 120 days,
| the "on" state stays active. 
*/
b {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: all 0s 10368000s;
}
/*
| -These rulesets override the long duration 
| time.
*/
.u:active + b.usd,
.g:active + a.u + b.usd,
.y:active + b.yen,
.r:active + a.y + b.yen,
.e:active + b.eur,
.b:active + a.e + b.eur {
  transition: all 0s;
}
.g:active + a.u + b.usd {
  opacity: 1;
  color: lime;
}
.u:active + b.usd.usd {
  opacity: 0;
}
.r:active + a.y + b.yen {
  opacity: 1;
  color: tomato;
}
.y:active + b.yen.yen {
  opacity: 0;
}
.b:active + a.e + b.eur {
  opacity: 1;
  color: cyan;
}
.e:active + b.eur.eur {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Currency Exchange</dt>
  <dd>
    <a href='#/' class="g">USD</a>
    <a href="#/" class='u'></a>
    <b class="usd">$1.00</b>
  </dd>
  <dd>
    <a href='#/' class="r">YEN</a>
    <a href='#/' class="y"></a>
    <b class='yen'>¥1.00</b>
  </dd>
  <dd>
    <a href='#/' class="b">EUR</a>
    <a href='#/' class="e"></a>
    <b class='eur'>€1.00</b>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

#### SNIPPET 1

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}
dt {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  color: gold;
}
a,
a:link,
a:visited {
  background: black;
  color: yellow;
  display: block;
}
a:hover,
a:active {
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
}
b#usd,
b#hkd,
b#eur,
b#yen,
b#pso,
b#drc {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
#usd1:focus + b,
#hkd2:focus + b,
#eur3:focus + b,
#yen4:focus + b,
#pso5:focus + b,
#drc6:focus + b {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  color: cyan;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
#usd:hover:after,
#hkd:hover:after,
#eur:hover:after,
#yen:hover:after,
#pso:hover:after,
#drc:hover:after {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Currency Display</dt>
  <dd>
    <a href="#/" id="usd1">USD</a> 
    <b id="usd">USD</b>
    <a href="#/" id="hkd2">HKD</a>
    <b id="hkd">HKD</b>
    <a href="#/" id="eur3">EUR</a> 
    <b id="eur">EUR</b> 
    <a href="#/" id="yen4">YEN</a>
    <b id="yen">YEN</b>
    <a href="#/" id="pso5">PSO</a> 
    <b id="pso">PSO</b> 
    <a href="#/" id="drc6">DRC</a>
    <b id="drc">DRC</b>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: thank you for posting your solution. I didn't mention in my comment that I updated the question but one of the clarifications was that I want the currency that is being displayed to remain on screen after clicking elsewhere, which was poorly communicated the first time around. Is there anyway to have that?

Comment: @Simon I managed to use a bad hack but the target elements are definitely in a perpetual state.