# how to add a class when an html element is selected

Tags: html, css

My application has several buttons (say b1,b2,b3) which I am using as navigation menu items (alternate to using `<a>`). I want to change the color of the button when it is clicked/selected. When a particular button is clicked (say b1), its color should change to say `red` and all b2,b3 should have color `grey`. When `b2` is selected, it should be red and `b1` should switch back to `grey`. Is there a way I can do so using `css` and `pseudo` elements (something similar to `:hover`)?

Comment: Pretty sure this is not possible with css only..  You'll need javascript to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep :active css style after click a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31178653/how-to-keep-active-css-style-after-click-a-button)

Answer (score -1):

A good strategy is to have a class `isClicked` which have the styles of the clicked element, and toggle everytime the element is clicked,say:

I use jquery to show the logic behind it :D

```js
$('div').click(function(){  
  $('div.isClicked').toggleClass('isClicked')
  $(this).toggleClass('isClicked')
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  margin:10px auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align:center;
  
  background-color:grey;
}

div.isClicked {
  background-color:red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>C</div>
```

Comment: The question is not tagged `jQuery` so why are you using that?

Comment: @volt It's not possible with just the tagged languages so there's not really any harm in introducing an arbitrary 3rd option.

Comment: I understand and agree @TylerH but why load jQuery for this when it's possible with vanilla JS?

Comment: @volt Probably because Kristian prefers jQuery. Or because it's more complicated in vanilla JS. Or some other reason. Take your pick.