# I want add male/female with help of this div and image into data base

Tags: php

Here is my code. it shows two image with male and female in different divs.I want add data if user select male or female into database. How can insert my data into database ?

```
  <div class="gender-part answer">
                  <a href="javascript:;">
                    <div class="male true">
                      <img src="images/male-enable.png" alt="">
                      <div class="popup popup-male"  name="gender" value="male">Male</div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                  <a href="javascript:;">
                    <div class="female false">
                      <img src="images/female-enable.png" alt="" >
                      <div class="popup popup-female" name="gender" value="female">Female</div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </div> <!-- gender-part -->
```

Comment: Are you gonna submit the for directly to a PHP page or with AJAX or something else?

Comment: I want to add page with help of php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Image instead of radio button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541614/use-image-instead-of-radio-button)

Comment: @NijrajGelani yes but i want to insert data into database how can i do that?

Comment: @siddhesh no idea where to start !!

Comment: Please search in google form processing and storing it in db using php there are plenty of articles to learn the php and this type of stuff that you asked.

Comment: @siddhesh i know how to insert data in php in simple way but its looks like different this code using div and image for that what should i do to insert male/female into data base?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the javascript for such kind of thing.
For Example
Make one hidden input field

```
<input id="gender" type="hidden" name="gender" value="male" />
```

and whenever you are clicking on image set the appropriate value to this one.

```
$("#gender").val("male");
```

if someone clicks female image then

```
$("#gender").val("female");
```

**NOTE**: don't forget to put hidden input field withing the form element.

Comment: You will get the gender key in $_POST array after submitting the form then you have to fire the sql query as normal.

Comment: yes i have tried as u said but its only shows male. if i select female it also shows male.

Comment: check the inspector after clicking on female image value of input hidden field.