# How to use images in anchor tags as input?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code:

```
 <section class="mood" role="listbox">
 <a class="#" role="option">1<img src="http://s.goose.im/emoji/emoji_u1f622.png"></a>
 <a class="#" role="option">2<img src="http://s.goose.im/emoji/emoji_u1f610.png"></a> 
 <a class="#" role="option">3<img src="http://s.goose.im/emoji/emoji_u1f603.png"></a>
 <a class="#" role="option">4<img src="http://s.goose.im/emoji/emoji_u1f60a.png"></a>
</section>`
```

I want these images to act as radio input buttons. How do I do that? Also, I'm a beginner and I don't want to mess up the css for the `<a>` tag.
Can I do it without the input tag using some script? And if I do use the input tag, can I still save myself from redoing the css?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541614/use-image-instead-of-radio-button

Comment: hi , pls refer this link http://jsbin.com/image-instead-of-radio-button/3/edit?html,css,output

Comment: It's also not clear what you want to happen when you click. How will you see which one of them was last clicked (which one is selected at the moment)?

Comment: Have a look at this link http://codersblock.com/blog/checkbox-trickery-with-css/. It shows different innovative ways to use checkboxes/radio buttons. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use a regular HTML form with labels?

**HTML:**

```
<form class="mood" role="listbox">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="1" /><img src="http://s.goose.im/emoji/emoji_u1f622.png"></label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="2" /><img src="http://s.goose.im/emoji/emoji_u1f610.png"></label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="3" /><img src="http://s.goose.im/emoji/emoji_u1f603.png"></label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="4" /><img src="http://s.goose.im/emoji/emoji_u1f60a.png"></label>
</form>
```

Images will act as radio box too i.e you can select a radio box when you click on image.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/1070/