# Check Box / Radio Button line wrap issue

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to prevent separation of label and check box (or radio button) when there is a line wrap. Unfortunately I'm working with some very long labels over which I have no control.

It would be awesome if there could be columns where all the buttons align, but at a minimum, no splitting up of items.

thanks in advance.

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.html_S {
 height: 100%;

}
.toast {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
.body_S {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
 font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
 background-color: transparent !important;
}

.reqSpan_S {
    top: -15px;
 position:relative;
}

.reqFieldText_S {
    color: red;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.reqFieldStar_S {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.k-button {
   color: red;
}

.buttonCentre_S {
    text-align: center;
}

.outerDiv_S {
    width: 85%;
    margin: 50px auto;
    text-align: center;
}
#surveyForm {
 top: -35px;
 position:relative;
    width: 85%;
 margin: 50px auto;
 text-align: left;
}
#surveyForm fieldset {
 background: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 padding: 20px 30px;
 
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 10%;
}

/*inputs*/
#surveyForm input, #surveyForm textarea {
 padding: 15px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: montserrat;
 color: #2C3E50;
 font-size: 13px;
}
/*buttons*/
#surveyForm .action-button {
    text-align: center;
 width: 100px;
 background: #27AE60;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 10px 5px;
 margin: 10px 5px;
}
#surveyForm .action-button:hover, #surveyForm .action-button:focus {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}
#surveyForm .action-button-submit {
 width: 100px;
 background: #3498db;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 10px 5px;
 margin: 10px 5px;
}

/*For Toast not part of surveyForm...*/
.action-button-ok {
 width: 100px;
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 10px 5px;
 margin: 10px 5px;
}

#surveyForm .action-button-submit:hover, #surveyForm .action-button-submit:focus {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #3498db;
}
/*headings*/
.fs-title {
 font-size: 15px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #2C3E50;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fs-subtitle {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #666;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 overflow: hidden;
 /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
 counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
 list-style-type: none;
 color: white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 9px;

 /* width should be 100 divided by the number of steps */
 /* this is set in the code dynamically in javascript */
 width: 6.25%;

 float: left;
 position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
 content: counter(step);
 counter-increment: step;
 width: 20px;
 line-height: 20px;
 display: block;
 font-size: 10px;
 color: #333;
 background: white;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
 content: '';
 width: 100%;
 height: 2px;
 background: white;
 position: absolute;
 left: -50%;
 top: 9px;
 z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
 /*connector not needed before the first step*/
 content: none; 
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
 background: #27AE60;
 color: white;
}

.k-dropdown {
    width: 100%;
}
.k-state-selected.k-state-focused {
    background-color: #27AE60;
    border: 0;
}

#surveyForm hr {
    border: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/*  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17541916/1550052   */


.rad,
.ckb{
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
.rad > input,
.ckb > input{ /* HIDE ORG RADIO & CHECKBOX */
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
/* RADIO & CHECKBOX STYLES */
.rad > i,
.ckb > i{     /* DEFAULT <i> STYLE */
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width:  16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 8px #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  background: #666;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
/* CHECKBOX OVERWRITE STYLES */
.ckb > i {
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.rad:hover > i{ /* HOVER <i> STYLE */
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #fff;
  background: #666;
}
.rad > input:checked + i{ /* (RADIO CHECKED) <i> STYLE */
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #fff;
  background: #27AE60;
}
/* CHECKBOX */
.ckb > input + i:after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 12px;
  width:  12px;
  margin: 2px;
  border-radius: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
  background: #d3d3d3;
}
.ckb > input:checked + i:after{ /* (RADIO CHECKED) <i> STYLE */
  margin-left: 11px;
  background:  #27AE60; 
}
```

```html
<body  class='body_S'> 


 <form id='surveyForm'>
        

        
  <!-- fieldsets -->
  <fieldset >
<h2 class="fs-title">
 Demographic Search Criteria 
</h2>
<h2 class="fs-subtitle">
 The demographic data you select here will be used by planners
</h2>
<h2 class="fs-subtitle">
 1
</h2>
<label>Main Type of Business
</label>
<br />

<label class="ckb" for="cb-638-0">
<input type="checkbox" name="cb-638" id="cb-638-0" value="3223" />

<i></i>Accommodations
</label>
<label class="ckb" for="cb-638-1">
<input type="checkbox"  name="cb-638" id="cb-638-1" value="3224" />

<i></i>Activities, Attractions & Tours
</label>
<label class="ckb" for="cb-638-2">
<input type="checkbox"  name="cb-638" id="cb-638-2" value="3225" />

<i></i>Association
</label>
<label class="ckb" for="cb-638-3">
<input type="checkbox"  name="cb-638" id="cb-638-3" value="3226" />

<i></i>Convention and Visitors Bureau
</label>
<label class="ckb" for="cb-638-4">
<input type="checkbox" name="cb-638" id="cb-638-4" value="3227" />

<i></i>Convention Centre
</label>
<label class="ckb" for="cb-638-5">
<input type="checkbox"  name="cb-638" id="cb-638-5" value="3228" />

<i></i>Cruise Line
</label>
<label class="ckb" for="cb-638-6">
<input type="checkbox"  name="cb-638" id="cb-638-6" value="3229" />

<i></i>Destination Management Company
</label>
<label class="ckb" for="cb-638-7">
<input type="checkbox"  name="cb-638" id="cb-638-7" value="3230" />

<i></i>Destination Marketing Organization
</label>
<label class="ckb" for="cb-638-8">
<input type="checkbox"  name="cb-638" id="cb-638-8" value="3231" />

<i></i>Event Service Provider
</label>
<label class="ckb" for="cb-638-9">
<input type="checkbox"  name="cb-638" id="cb-638-9" value="3232" />

<i></i>Technology Provider
</label>
<label class="ckb" for="cb-638-10">
<input type="checkbox" name="cb-638" id="cb-638-10" value="3233" />

<i></i>Transportation
</label>
<label class="ckb" for="cb-638-11">
<input type="checkbox"  name="cb-638" id="cb-638-11" value="3234" />

<i></i>Tourism Board
</label>
<label class="ckb" for="cb-638-12">
<input type="checkbox"  name="cb-638" id="cb-638-12" value="3235" />

<i></i>Venues for Meeting/Events (non-hotel)
</label>




</fieldset>



        
 </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

css for the select groups starts at line 207 of the css section. Its from this stack overflow solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17541916/155005

Comment: This is a tabular data, simply, place them in two columns table.

Comment: Try using the `for` html attribute to be able to separate label and input and keep the connection between the two. Along with the CSS `white-space:nowrap` property and value. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_label_for.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add float: left; to you label tags

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.html_S {
 height: 100%;

}
.toast {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
.body_S {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
 font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
 background-color: transparent !important;
}

.reqSpan_S {
    top: -15px;
 position:relative;
}

.reqFieldText_S {
    color: red;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.reqFieldStar_S {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.k-button {
   color: red;
}

.buttonCentre_S {
    text-align: center;
}

.outerDiv_S {
    width: 85%;
    margin: 50px auto;
    text-align: center;
}
#surveyForm {
 top: -35px;
 position:relative;
    width: 85%;
 margin: 50px auto;
 text-align: left;
}
#surveyForm fieldset {
 background: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 padding: 20px 30px;
 
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 10%;
}

/*inputs*/
#surveyForm input, #surveyForm textarea {
 padding: 15px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: montserrat;
 color: #2C3E50;
 font-size: 13px;
}
/*buttons*/
#surveyForm .action-button {
    text-align: center;
 width: 100px;
 background: #27AE60;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 10px 5px;
 margin: 10px 5px;
}
#surveyForm .action-button:hover, #surveyForm .action-button:focus {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}
#surveyForm .action-button-submit {
 width: 100px;
 background: #3498db;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 10px 5px;
 margin: 10px 5px;
}

/*For Toast not part of surveyForm...*/
.action-button-ok {
 width: 100px;
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 10px 5px;
 margin: 10px 5px;
}

#surveyForm .action-button-submit:hover, #surveyForm .action-button-submit:focus {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #3498db;
}
/*headings*/
.fs-title {
 font-size: 15px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #2C3E50;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fs-subtitle {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #666;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 overflow: hidden;
 /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
 counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
 list-style-type: none;
 color: white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 9px;

 /* width should be 100 divided by the number of steps */
 /* this is set in the code dynamically in javascript */
 width: 6.25%;

 float: left;
 position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
 content: counter(step);
 counter-increment: step;
 width: 20px;
 line-height: 20px;
 display: block;
 font-size: 10px;
 color: #333;
 background: white;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
 content: '';
 width: 100%;
 height: 2px;
 background: white;
 position: absolute;
 left: -50%;
 top: 9px;
 z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
 /*connector not needed before the first step*/
 content: none; 
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
 background: #27AE60;
 color: white;
}

.k-dropdown {
    width: 100%;
}
.k-state-selected.k-state-focused {
    background-color: #27AE60;
    border: 0;
}

#surveyForm hr {
    border: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/*  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17541916/1550052   */


.rad,
.ckb{
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  padding: 10px;
  clear: left;
  float: left;
}
.rad > input,
.ckb > input{ /* HIDE ORG RADIO & CHECKBOX */
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
/* RADIO & CHECKBOX STYLES */
.rad > i,
.ckb > i{     /* DEFAULT <i> STYLE */
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width:  16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 8px #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  background: #666;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
/* CHECKBOX OVERWRITE STYLES */
.ckb > i {
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.rad:hover > i{ /* HOVER <i> STYLE */
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #fff;
  background: #666;
}
.rad > input:checked + i{ /* (RADIO CHECKED) <i> STYLE */
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #fff;
  background: #27AE60;
}
/* CHECKBOX */
.ckb > input + i:after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 12px;
  width:  12px;
  margin: 2px;
  border-radius: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
  background: #d3d3d3;
}
.ckb > input:checked + i:after{ /* (RADIO CHECKED) <i> STYLE */
  margin-left: 11px;
  background:  #27AE60; 
}
```

```html
<body  class='body_S'> 


 <form id='surveyForm'>
        

        
  <!-- fieldsets -->
  <fieldset >
<h2 class="fs-title">
 Demographic Search Criteria for iBE Appointment Scheduler For Your Company Profile
</h2>
<h2 class="fs-subtitle">
 The demographic data you select here will be used by planners to help search and identify exhibitors they want to request meetings with. The data you fill in will default on all your booth staff members' profiles, however they can 
edit the selections to customize it to what they offer if it differs from what you offer.
</h2>
<h2 class="fs-subtitle">
 1
</h2>
<label>Main Type of Business
</label>
<br />

<label class="ckb" for="cb-638-0">
<input type="checkbox" name="cb-638" id="cb-638-0" value="3223" />

<i></i>Accommodations
</label>
<label class="ckb" for="cb-638-1">
<input type="checkbox"  name="cb-638" id="cb-638-1" value="3224" />

<i></i>Activities, Attractions & Tours
</label>
<label class="ckb" for="cb-638-2">
<input type="checkbox"  name="cb-638" id="cb-638-2" value="3225" />

<i></i>Association
</label>
<label class="ckb" for="cb-638-3">
<input type="checkbox"  name="cb-638" id="cb-638-3" value="3226" />

<i></i>Convention and Visitors Bureau
</label>
<label class="ckb" for="cb-638-4">
<input type="checkbox" name="cb-638" id="cb-638-4" value="3227" />

<i></i>Convention Centre
</label>
<label class="ckb" for="cb-638-5">
<input type="checkbox"  name="cb-638" id="cb-638-5" value="3228" />

<i></i>Cruise Line
</label>
<label class="ckb" for="cb-638-6">
<input type="checkbox"  name="cb-638" id="cb-638-6" value="3229" />

<i></i>Destination Management Company
</label>
<label class="ckb" for="cb-638-7">
<input type="checkbox"  name="cb-638" id="cb-638-7" value="3230" />

<i></i>Destination Marketing Organization
</label>
<label class="ckb" for="cb-638-8">
<input type="checkbox"  name="cb-638" id="cb-638-8" value="3231" />

<i></i>Event Service Provider
</label>
<label class="ckb" for="cb-638-9">
<input type="checkbox"  name="cb-638" id="cb-638-9" value="3232" />

<i></i>Technology Provider
</label>
<label class="ckb" for="cb-638-10">
<input type="checkbox" name="cb-638" id="cb-638-10" value="3233" />

<i></i>Transportation
</label>
<label class="ckb" for="cb-638-11">
<input type="checkbox"  name="cb-638" id="cb-638-11" value="3234" />

<i></i>Tourism Board
</label>
<label class="ckb" for="cb-638-12">
<input type="checkbox"  name="cb-638" id="cb-638-12" value="3235" />

<i></i>Venues for Meeting/Events (non-hotel)
</label>




</fieldset>



        
 </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want don't want everything on a new line. I want an intelligent wrap

Comment: Check out the updated answer. Is this what you want?

Comment: I had to use clear: left; to reset the float on stuff following the check boxes (not in the snippet),  if anybody is following this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specifically prevent line breaks within the `label` element, there is CSS for that:

```css
label.chk, label.rad {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

---

If you want to allow line breaks but not if they would occur between the control and the beginning of the label, you may be able to adjust your code like this:

```css
.nowrap {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<label class="ckb" for="cb-638-1">
<span class="nowrap"><input type="checkbox"  name="cb-638" id="cb-638-1" value="3224" />
<i></i>Activities,</span> Attractions & Tours
</label>
```

(You'll also need to modify the `.chk > ...` and `.rad > ...` rules to account for the additional `span`.)

---

If you're satisfied with the labels just being columnar, just make `label` a block level element:

```css
label {
  display:block;
}
```