# Input options (radio and checkbox) has buttons with icons

Tags: html, css, jpeg

Is there any library available that converts options or radion inputs has selectble buttons with icons? Example of what type of styling looking for is above.
[image]

Comment: Use this one: http://codepen.io/JiveDig/pen/jbdJXR

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541614/use-image-instead-of-radio-button

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure stackoverflow is the right place to ask these kinda questions, but these are useful for you:

```
 1. <http://codepen.io/DavidBradbury/pen/HuCqx>
```

2. https://gist.github.com/rcotrina94/7828886
 3. [Use Image instead of radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541614/use-image-instead-of-radio-button)

And you possibly duplicating the last one.

> This snippet from codepen, here to stay:

```css
.input-hidden {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label>img {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #090;
}

/* Stuff after this is only to make things more pretty */
input[type=radio] + label>img {
  border: 1px dashed #444;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  transition: 500ms all;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label>img {
  transform: 
    rotateZ(-10deg) 
    rotateX(10deg);
}

/*
 | //lea.verou.me/css3patterns
 | Because white bgs are boring.
*/
html {
  background-color: #fff;
  background-size: 100% 1.2em;
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(
      90deg, 
      transparent 79px, 
      #abced4 79px, 
      #abced4 81px, 
      transparent 81px
    ),
    linear-gradient(
      #eee .1em, 
      transparent .1em
    );
}
```

```html
<input 
  type="radio" name="emotion" 
  id="sad" class="input-hidden" />
<label for="sad">
  <img 
    src="//placekitten.com/150/150" 
    alt="I'm sad" />
</label>

<input 
  type="radio" name="emotion"
  id="happy" class="input-hidden" />
<label for="happy">
  <img 
    src="//placekitten.com/151/151" 
    alt="I'm happy" />
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a library to do it.

> HTML:

```
<input type="radio" id="example"/>
<label for="example"><i>youricon</i>Text</label>
```

> CSS:

```
input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

label {
    //......button layout
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this yourself, this easy, do changes background-images

```
<label class="check">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span>Value</span>
</label>
```

CSS

```
.check {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 40px;
}

.check input {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
}

.check span:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background:#000;
}

.check input:checked + span:before {
    background: red;
}
```

Live demo JsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/grinmax_/7fpbkz9s/