# radiobuttons with thumbnails in material design

Tags: html, css, radio-button, material-design, thumbnails

I am working with [material design lite](https://getmdl.io/) . Right now I need to implement some kind of radio buttons where I am going to display 4 thumbnails to the user and they must choose one of them. Is there any already created component to do that? Or can someone tell the starting point to make it?

I really think that the nest idea is use radio buttons but then I need to set them the images and I don't know how to do it. I am using plain HTML

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Image instead of radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541614/use-image-instead-of-radio-button)

Comment: As far as I can tell this does not exist already in the MDL framework so you would have to implement it yourself. This can be done with help of the article I mentioned as a duplicate.