# Image as Radio Button

Tags: html, css, image, radio-button

I want to use and modify this code. I need the image src from the css directly in the HTML code. But if I insert the background image directly in the input, it does not work. does anyone know a solution?

```css
.cc-selector input{
    margin:0;padding:0;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
       -moz-appearance:none;
            appearance:none;
}

.visa{background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/lXzJ1eB.png);}
.mastercard{background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/SJbRQF7.png);}

.drinkcard-cc, .cc-selector input:active +.drinkcard-cc{opacity: .9;}
.drinkcard-cc, .cc-selector input:checked +.drinkcard-cc{
    -webkit-filter: none;
       -moz-filter: none;
            filter: none;
}
.drinkcard-cc{
    cursor:pointer;
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;height:70px;
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
       -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
            transition: all 100ms ease-in;
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
       -moz-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
            filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
}
.drinkcard-cc:hover{
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
       -moz-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
            filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
}
```

```html
    <div class="cc-selector">
        <input checked="checked" id="visa" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="visa" />
        <label class="drinkcard-cc visa" for="visa"></label>
        <input id="mastercard" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="mastercard" />
        <label class="drinkcard-cc mastercard"for="mastercard"></label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Read This :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541614/use-images-instead-of-radio-buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're putting the images in the wrong place, they need to be applied to the `label`.

```css
.cc-selector input{
    margin:0;padding:0;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
       -moz-appearance:none;
            appearance:none;
}

.drinkcard-cc, .cc-selector input:active +.drinkcard-cc{opacity: .9;}
.drinkcard-cc, .cc-selector input:checked +.drinkcard-cc{
    -webkit-filter: none;
       -moz-filter: none;
            filter: none;
}
.drinkcard-cc{
    cursor:pointer;
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;height:70px;
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
       -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
            transition: all 100ms ease-in;
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
       -moz-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
            filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
}
.drinkcard-cc:hover{
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
       -moz-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
            filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
}
```

```html
<div class="cc-selector">
  <input checked="checked" id="visa" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="visa" />
  <label style="background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/lXzJ1eB.png);" class="drinkcard-cc visa" for="visa"></label>
  <input id="mastercard" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="mastercard" />
  <label style="background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/SJbRQF7.png);" class="drinkcard-cc mastercard"for="mastercard"></label>
</div>
```