# How to catch the displayed image ID in Laravel

Tags: html, css, laravel

I'm displaying a images from the database and i need to catch the image id from the controller .I'm trying to save image ID to Database

This is the image tag with contain image id
[image]

What we need to do is : When the user click the one of image and submit need to catch that selected id from the controller

[image: Image Display blade file]

```
    $kudos->receiveuserid =  $request->get('categories');
    $kudos->imageid =  'how can i get image ID'
```

Comment: is there any form or you are using ajax?

Comment: No I didn't use Ajax

Comment: then just use radio button next to your image and then write a javascript to select the respective radio button on click of an image

Comment: is there any form ?

Comment: @Fed you can just try to replace image wtih radio button and could fetch the value on form submission. in controller > action `$request` object. Here it's already answered how can replace image with radio button. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541614/use-images-instead-of-radio-buttons

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use images instead of radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541614/use-images-instead-of-radio-buttons)

Comment: hi @Fed, use hidden value below the image src, in image click event just get the id and push into the hidden value array using jQuery .

Comment: @kmgkumar there is a image loop how can i send the hidden specific value

Comment: @Fed create the chat room and invite we will discuss there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this and customize according to your requirement

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
<div>
    <img src="{{$category->image}}" class="imgRating">
    <input type="radio" value="{{$category->id}}" class="imgId" name="imageid">
</div>
@endforeach
```

Now in write a little jQuery

```
$(".imgRating").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".imgId").prop( "checked", true );
});
```

Finally, add CSS

```
.imgId{
    display:none !important;
}
```

Now in your controller you will get the selected image id by `$request->imageid`

Comment: Next time please post your code in writing instead of posting a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

try this it should work. the idea here is that when you click on the image, the javascript function gets the id and assign it to a modal form then you submit. you can modify it to suit your preference.

```
<!-- modal to get image id store it in hidden field-->
<div id="imgModal" class="modal fade" >
        <div class="modal-dialog box box-default" role="document" style="color:black;font-size:12.5px;">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <p class="modal-title">Image Form</p>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ url('img/addid/') }}" method="post"  role="form">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="modal-body">  
                <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0 10px;">

                     <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="imgid" name="imgid" value="">

                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Submit</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>

                </form>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

<!-- display image code-->
<div class="col-sm-3">
 <div class="form-group">
  @foreach($category as $category)

    <a onclick="imgfunc('{{ $category->id}}')"><img class="boxicon" src="{{ asset('kudosupload/badges/'. $category->image)}}" name="img" ></a>

         <br>
     @endforeach
  </div>
</div>


<!-- javascript to get image id when click on image-->
<script type="text/javascript">

function imgfunc(r)
    {
        document.getElementById('imgid').value = r;

        $("#imgModal").modal('show')
    }

</script>

//controller to get input and store in database
public function saveImage(Request $request){

                  $this->validate($request, [

                  'imgid' => 'required|string',

                ]);

                $imgid=$request->input('imgid');

                $datasave=DB::table('imgtable')->insert([

                  'id'=>imgid,


                ]);

              return redirect('url')->with('message','Image saved!');


   }

   //route

   Route::post('img/addid','controller@saveImage');
```