# Radio Button as Image Card

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm a very newbie to styling using CSS. I'm trying to add an Image card as a radio button. I referred to multiple articles in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17541916/14138027) and using [Codepen](https://jsfiddle.net/djibe89/at2cv9q1/).

I tried the following:

- Wrap a standard radio input within a `label`
- Within this `label`, just after the `input type="radio"`, now add a
  simple `div` styled as a card

```js
console.log($(".test:checked").val())
```

```css
/* HIDE RADIO */
[type=radio] { 
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
}

/* IMAGE STYLES */
[type=radio] + card {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
}

/* CHECKED STYLES */
[type=radio]:checked + card {
  outline: 2px solid #f00;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
}


/* Section */
section {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.cards {
    display: flex;
}

.card {
    position: relative;
    width: 17rem;
    height: 17rem;
    margin: .5rem;
    border: 1px solid #EEE;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-size: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-size .4s;
}

.card:hover {
    background-size: 110%;
}

.card::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 80px;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-size: 100%;
    transition: .2s;
}

.card:hover::before {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(5px);
    background-size: 110%;
}

.card .title {
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 1rem;
    transform: translateY(13.5rem);
    transition: .2s;
}

.card:hover .title {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(13rem);
}

.card.dark .title {
    color: white
}

.card.loan-business,
.card.loan-business::before {
    background-image: url("https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/bank-loan-small-business-flat-vector-concept_81522-3733.jpg");
}

.card.loan-personal,
.card.loan-personal::before {
    background-image: url("https://www.loanqubes.com/campaign/new-personal/images/banner-vector.png");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
<section>
    <ul class="cards">
            <li class="card loan-business">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="test" id="test" value="business">
                    </label>
                    <div class="title">
                            <h3>Business Loan</h3>
                    </div>
            </li>
            <li class="card loan-personal">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="test" id="test" value="personal">
                    </label>
                    <div class="title">
                            <h3>Personal Loan</h3>
                    </div>
            </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Thanks for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works, but the hit area for the radio inputs was too small and didn't match the size of the `.card` elements. To fix this set their `width` and `height` in CSS to `100%`.

Also note that the JS you were using to test needed to be amended to listen for the `change` event on the radios, not just output on page load. In addition you had duplicated the same `#test` id which is not valid HTML, as the values must be unique. I changed them to classes to address this.

```js
$('.test').on('change', e => console.log(e.target.value));
```

```css
[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

[type=radio]+card {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
}

[type=radio]:checked+card {
  outline: 2px solid #f00;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
}

section {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cards {
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 17rem;
  height: 17rem;
  margin: .5rem;
  border: 1px solid #EEE;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-size: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-size .4s;
}

.card:hover {
  background-size: 110%;
}

.card::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 80px;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-size: 100%;
  transition: .2s;
}

.card:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: blur(5px);
  background-size: 110%;
}

.card .title {
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 1rem;
  transform: translateY(13.5rem);
  transition: .2s;
}

.card:hover .title {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(13rem);
}

.card.dark .title {
  color: white
}

.card.loan-business,
.card.loan-business::before {
  background-image: url("https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/bank-loan-small-business-flat-vector-concept_81522-3733.jpg");
}

.card.loan-personal,
.card.loan-personal::before {
  background-image: url("https://www.loanqubes.com/campaign/new-personal/images/banner-vector.png");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section>
  <ul class="cards">
    <li class="card loan-business">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="test" class="test" value="business" />
      </label>
      <div class="title">
        <h3>Business Loan</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card loan-personal">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="test" class="test" value="personal" />
      </label>
      <div class="title">
        <h3>Personal Loan</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```