# Using image as Radio button in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use images as radio buttons but couldn't find any source. Any help will be appreciated.

[sample of radio button with images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiHNd.png)

Comment: Is there a particular UI library you are using?

Comment: i'm using material-ui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first hide your [type=radio] and then wrap your image and the input tag inside the label.

[This Stack Overflow link can be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17541916/8170092)

Answer (score 2):

Since the OP mentioned he is using Material-UI (you should add that tag next time BTW), take a look at the [Radio documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/radio/)

There are `icon` and `checkedIcon` props, to which you can pass the corresponding images to.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy, simply replace the text in the label with the image you want to add.
for example:

```
<FormControlLabel
              value="paypal"
              control={<Radio />}
              label={<img src="https://assets.stickpng.com/images/580b57fcd9996e24bc43c530.png" alt="paypal" style={{width: "80px"}} />}
            />
```

Here I'm using radio buttons of MUI