# Use images instead of radio buttons in React.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, laravel

I am doing a project using Laravel and react.js.
I need to select only one image out of this list of images :
[image]

The code of above picture,

```
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td class="cactus"> <img src="../assets/images/Echeveria-colorata.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image" /> Echeveria-colorata</td>
       <td class="cactus"><img src="../assets/images/Echeveria-imbricata.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image" />Echeveria-imbricata</td>
       <td class="cactus"><img src="../assets/images/Graptopetalum-paraguayense.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image" />Ghost Plant</td>
       <td class="cactus"><img src="../assets/images/Mammillaria-elongata.jpg"alt="Generic placeholder image" />Ladyfinger cactus</td>
      </tr><br />
     <tr>
       <td class="cactus"><img src="../assets/images/Graptopetalum-paraguayense.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image" />Ghost Plant</td>
       <td class="cactus"><img src="../assets/images/Bunny-Ears.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image" />Bunny-Ears</td>
       <td class="cactus"><img src="../assets/images/Echeveria-colorata.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image" />Echeveria-colorata</td>
       <td class="cactus"><img src="../assets/images/Echeveria-imbricata.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image" />Echeveria-imbricata</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Thank you for your Help!

Comment: Seems you could use [css instead](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+use+images+as+radio+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541614/use-images-instead-of-radio-buttons?

Comment: Thank you @TusharShahi . Its working now