# Is it possbile to make heart shaped input html button/element?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to customise regular `<input tupe="checkbox">` ?Lets say i want it to be heart shape input element, and that heart changes color when its selected.

I was looking at this 2 articles, first [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox) on MDN and i didnt see anything that can help me. Is there something I am missing is this even possbile?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541614/use-images-instead-of-radio-buttons/17541916

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I make HTML Anchors with 'name' or 'id'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/should-i-make-html-anchors-with-name-or-id)

Comment: Not i has nothing to do with my question. Let me add more descirtiption to question itself.

Comment: I'm guessing a combination of searching for "css custom check box" and "css heart shape" would be a good place to start.

Comment: Yeah.. and I didnt think of that.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp

Comment: [SVG](https://www.svgrepo.com/svg/13666/heart) or [Unicode](https://www.htmlsymbols.xyz/heart-symbols) could help you aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hide the checkbox itself with `input { display none; }`. Then add the heart either as SVG or as HTML/Unicode within the label. YOu can use `input:checked ~ label` as selector to add changes within CSS.

```css
/* hides the checkbox */
input {
  display: none;
}

/* changes the color when selected */
input:checked ~ label {
  color: red;
}



/* for styling purpose only */
label {
  font-size: 5em;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="heart">
<label for="heart">&#9829</label>
```

Comment: Thank you. So i needed to hid checkbox itself and to "fake" it as a label.