# set image as background for radio button

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have this in my css & html:

```css
    .color-choose input[type="radio"]#red + label span {
    /* background: url('https://content.rolex.com/dam/2021/upright-bba/m124200-0001.png?impolicy=v6-upright') */
    background-color: #000;
     }
```

```html
<input data-image="red" type="radio" id="red" name="color" value="red" checked>
<label for="red"><span></span></label>
```

what I am trying to do is have the background of the button to be the image, instead of the color. is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use images instead of radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541614/use-images-instead-of-radio-buttons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this CSS and remove the `data-image` property

```
input[type="radio"]{
   display:none;
}

input[type="radio"] + label
{
    background-image:url(http://example.com/radio_image.png);
    background-size: 24px 24px;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label
{
    background-image:url(http://example.com/radio_image_checked.png);
}
```