# Convert Radio Buttons to Look like Image 2

Tags: html, css, reactjs, radio-button

I have been designing a form where i need to change the UI of Radio buttons as show in image 1 to to as shown in Image 2.

Image1:

[image: Image1]

Image2:

[image: Image2]

```html
<div className="col-lg-12 form-items quote">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <RadioGroup
                row
                aria-labelledby="demo-controlled-radio-buttons-group"
                name="Base_material"
                // value={formValues["Base_material"]}
                onChange={handleChange}
                defaultValue="FR-4"
            >
                <FormControlLabel
                    value="FR-4"
                    control={<Radio />}
                    label="FR-4"
                />
                <FormControlLabel
                    value="Aluminium"
                    control={<Radio />}
                    label="Aluminium"
                />
            </RadioGroup>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I make look the radio buttons like Image 2.

Comment: one solution would be hide radio buttons and use div to show the layout and trigger click event on the div for radio button.

Comment: Is [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541614/use-images-instead-of-radio-buttons/17541916#17541916) what you are looking for?

Comment: Link below may help: [Use images instead of radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541614/use-images-instead-of-radio-buttons/17541916#17541916)