# How to replace toggle button in radio button with image

Tags: html, jquery, css

The task I have is to create a tri-state radio button/ switch and change the button to an image.

I have found the following example [here](https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/wvPRrQG). Which gives the following:

[image]

Although it's useful, I specifically need to replace the button itself with an image. So, the button(image) moves when the user toggles it on/ neutral/ off. The look and feel I'm trying to create (where the purple box is an image):

Centred:

[image]

Right toggled:

[image]

Left toggled:

[image]

I've used example #1 mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17541916/20331138) for inspiration, and I've tried manipulating the code as follows...

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #00c6ff 10%, #0072ff 90%); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
  background:    -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #00c6ff 10%, #0072ff 90%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background:     -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #00c6ff 10%, #0072ff 90%); /* IE10 */
  background:      -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #00c6ff 10%, #0072ff 90%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background:         linear-gradient(90deg, #00c6ff 10%, #0072ff 90%); /* W3C */
        
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.radio-wrapper {
    width: 145px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    border-radius: 30px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 1%;
    p {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 10;
        color: white;
        font-size: 1.7em;
        margin: 0;
        margin-top: 13px;
    }
    .correct {
        left: 17px;
        top: -5px;
    }
    .wrong {
        right: 17px;
        top: -5px;
    }
    .neutral-icon {
        left: 69px;
        top: -8px;
        opacity: .5;
    }
    label {
        z-index: 9;
    }
  img {
      z-index: 100;
  }
}

input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

.ion-close-round { 
  z-index: 99;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.neutral-icon i {
  font-size: 10px;
}
.neutral + img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 33%;
    transition: transform 1s;
}

.neutral:checked + img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}

.yes + label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.yes:checked + label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgb(32, 213, 50);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(32, 213, 50, 1) 0%, rgba(28, 195, 1, 1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(32, 213, 50, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(28, 195, 1, 1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(32, 213, 50, 1) 0%, rgba(28, 195, 1, 1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(32, 213, 50, 1) 0%, rgba(28, 195, 1, 1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(32, 213, 50, 1) 0%, rgba(28, 195, 1, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(32, 213, 50, 1) 0%, rgba(28, 195, 1, 1) 100%);
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    -moz-animation-name: slidein;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    -webkit-animation-name: slidein;
    animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: slidein;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}

.no + label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.no:checked + label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: red;
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    -moz-animation-name: slideno;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideno;
    animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: slideno;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    background: rgb(230, 108, 103);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(230, 108, 103, 1) 0%, rgba(221, 79, 75, 1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(230, 108, 103, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(221, 79, 75, 1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(230, 108, 103, 1) 0%, rgba(221, 79, 75, 1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(230, 108, 103, 1) 0%, rgba(221, 79, 75, 1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(230, 108, 103, 1) 0%, rgba(221, 79, 75, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(230, 108, 103, 1) 0%, rgba(221, 79, 75, 1) 100%);
}


@keyframes slidein {
    from {
        transform: translate(50px, 0);
    }
    to {
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
}


@keyframes slideno {
    from {
      transform: translate(-50px,0);
    }
    to {
        transform: translate( 0px, 0px);
    }
}

@keyframes returnLeft {
    from {
        transform: translate(-50px,0);
    }
    to {
        transform: translate(0px,0);
    }
}

@keyframes returnRight {
    from {
        transform: translate(50px,0);
    }
    to {
        transform: translate(0px,0);
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>Tri-state Toggle Button</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="radio-wrapper">
    <p class="correct"><i class="ion-checkmark-round"></i>
    </p>
    <p class="neutral-icon"><i class="ion-record"></i>
    </p>
    <p class="wrong"><i class="ion-close-round"></i></p>
    <input type="radio" name="event" class="yes" id="radio-yes" />

    <label for="radio-yes"></label>

    <input type="radio" name="event" class="neutral" checked id="radio-neutral" img src="[link to image here]"/>
    <img for="radio-neutral"></img>


    <input type="radio" name="event" class="no" id="radio-no" />
    <label for="radio-no"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, for some reason the button appears behind the radio button wrapper, I also can't select the central toggle and I can't seem to fix that...

I get something looking like this:

[image]

Comment: one possible solution could be 
Make two buttons and on click event replace the button. It will give you the same effect if you want to go with image idea.

Comment: @LaeeqKhanNiazi can you elaborate? I'm not sure it solves what's required, but I'm interested to see your solution in action...

Answer (score 1):

1. In HTML: If you don't need the label on the bar, you can just remove the value of 'One' 'Two' 'Three' or change it but not the id.
2. In CSS: You may just change the background into **background:url("../img/youricon.png") center center no-repeat;**
   in the input#one:checked/ input#two:checked/ input#three:checked property.

I found the reference from here:
https://www.sliderrevolution.com/resources/styling-radio-buttons/
hope it could help!

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  width: 14rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  font-family: verdana;
  &:before {
    content: '  ';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3rem;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 30px;
  }
  &__label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 2rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: color 200ms ease-out;
    &:hover {
      color: white;
    }
  }
  &__indicator {
    width: 4rem;
    height: 4rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: -.5rem;
    left: 0;
    background: blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: transform 600ms cubic-bezier(.02,.94,.09,.97),
                background 300ms cubic-bezier(.17,.67,.14,1.03);
    transform: translate3d(1rem,0,0);
  }

  input#one:checked ~ .switch__indicator {
    background: PaleGreen;
    transform: translate3d(1.2rem,0,0);
  }
  input#two:checked ~ .switch__indicator {
    background: MediumTurquoise;
    transform: translate3d(5.5rem,0,0);
  }
  input#three:checked ~ .switch__indicator {
    background: PaleVioletRed;
    transform: translate3d(10.6rem,0,0);
  }
  input[type="radio"] {
    &:not(:checked),
    &:checked {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="switch">
  <input name="switch" id="one" type="radio" checked/>
  <label for="one" class="switch__label">One</label>
  <input name="switch" id="two" type="radio" />
  <label for="two" class="switch__label">Two</label>
  <input name="switch" id="three" type="radio" />
  <label for="three" class="switch__label" >Three</label>
  <div class="switch__indicator" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found an alternative that does what I'm after.

It isn't the radio button solution, but it uses a slider and offers three toggle modes.

Code here:

```css
.slide-container {
  width: 300px;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: grey;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: url('https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/ahJtMe0vfOlAu1XJVQ6rcaGrQBgtrEZQefHy7SXB7jpijKhu1Kkox90XDuH8RmcBOXNn');
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 23px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: url('https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/ahJtMe0vfOlAu1XJVQ6rcaGrQBgtrEZQefHy7SXB7jpijKhu1Kkox90XDuH8RmcBOXNn');
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-container">
     <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" step="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>
```