# How to layout ASP.Net RadioButtons with Images?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

i need to layout a RabioButtons with Images. but i dont know how. How can i achieve a layout like the one in the image with ASP.Net RadioButtons and HTML/CSS.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create radio button with images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086098/how-to-create-radio-button-with-images)

Comment: But these are HTML RadioButton, i need a solution for ASP.Net RadioButtons

Answer (score 3):

Try This

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListItem item;
    int i = 0;
    System.IO.FileInfo file;

    var Images =
        from n in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("Images"))
        orderby n descending
        select n;

    foreach (var filename in Images)
    {
        file = new System.IO.FileInfo(filename);

        item = new ListItem("<img src='" + "Images/" + file.Name + "' alt='" + file.Name +
            "' title='"+file.Name+"'/>", i.ToString());

        RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(item);
        RadioButtonList1.CellPadding = 5;
        RadioButtonList1.CellSpacing = 5;
        i++;
    }
}


    <div>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1"
        runat="server"
        BorderStyle="Groove"
        BorderWidth="1px"
        RepeatColumns="3"
        RepeatLayout="Table">
    </asp:RadioButtonList> 
</div>
```

[Source](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deepak.sharma00/display-images-in-radiobuttonlist-control-in-Asp-Net/)

Answer (score 2):

```
<div>
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="myRadioBtnList" runat="server" >
<asp:ListItem Text="&lt;img src=&quot;download.jpg&quot;/&gt;" Value="1">         </asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Text="&lt;img src=&quot;download.jpg&quot;/&gt;" Value="2">   </asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="&lt;img src=&quot;download.jpg&quot;/&gt;" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Text="&lt;img src=&quot;download.jpg&quot;/&gt;" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
 </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </div>
```

in text  property replace download.jpg with your image path. i think this would help you